# Are there any stories of what Lord Krishna did after the Mahabharata till his departure from the world?

Tags: krishna

There are a lot of stories and anecdotes about Lord Krishna right from his birth till the part he played in Mahabharata and the curse of Gandhari. Then there is nothing till his death, a period of 36 years. I was wondering if there are any stories for that period ? or any mention in any of the scriptures ?

Comment: Bhagawata Purana mentions few like sages' curse on Yadavas, Udhava Gita, Yadava retires to Prabhasha region, etc...

Comment: Ya...that is all related to the destruction of Dwarka and his death but nothing about the 36 years in between...